# Implement __init__ in wtforms, Flask

Tags: python, object, flask, init, wtforms

I try to create a Form in Flask with the module WTForms, the problem is that I need to create a constructor to initialize some variables that use into the Form.

The code is the next:

startup.py

```
@app.route( "/startup/new", methods=["GET"] )
def formNewStartUp(  ):

     newForm = NewStartUpForm(request.form)

     return render_template( "platform/startup/new.html", newForm=newForm.getForm() )
```

newStartUpForm.py

```
class NewStartUpForm( Form ):

     # Constructor
     def __init__( self, *arg, **kwarg ):
         self.aCategories = StartupCategories(  )  # Another class
         self.lang = getUserLanguage( request )    # Language

     def getForm( self, *arg, **kwarg ):

         # Detail Main
         titleStartup = TextField()
         webStartup = TextField()
         groupStartUp = SelectField( 'Groups' )
         categoryStartUp = SelectField( 'Categories', choices=self.aCategories.getAllCategoriesByLang( self.lang ) )
         shortDescription = TextAreaField()
```

After initialize the Object I call to the "getForm()" function to load the Form, but when I'm in the HTML side the output is "None".

What am I using bad?

Answer (score 2):

It is normal you get none because `get_form()` method doesnt return anything. Something like below should work for you:

```
class NewStartUpForm( Form ):
    def __init__( self, *arg, **kwarg ):
        self.aCategories = StartupCategories()
        self.lang = getUserLanguage(request)
     def getForm( self, *arg, **kwarg ):
        choices=self.aCategories.getAllCategoriesByLang(self.lang)
        return SecondForm(choices)

class SecondForm(Form):
    titleStartup = TextField()
    webStartup = TextField()
    groupStartUp = SelectField('Groups')
    categoryStartUp = SelectField('Categories')
    shortDescription = TextAreaField()
    def __init__(self, choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.categoryStartUp.choices = choices
```